# Selenium : webdriver.Chorme() function problems

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver, chrome

I have difficulties in finding a solution, can you help me?
This is the code text:

```
from selenium import webdriver
web = webdriver.Chrome("C:\ Users\giova\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
web.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
```

This is the error that i receive when i run the program:

```
C:\Users\giova\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/giova/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py
C:\Users\giova\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py:2: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  web= webdriver.Chrome("C:\ Users\giova\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\giova\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Impossibile trovare il file specificato

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\giova\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    web= webdriver.Chrome("C:\ Users\giova\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
  File "C:\Users\giova\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "C:\Users\giova\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\giova\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home
```

Comment: is there a space before users ?

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting is

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Impossibile trovare il file specificato
```

My guess is, this is because of this line,

```
web = webdriver.Chrome("C:\ Users\giova\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
```

You might want to check the path "`C:\ Users\giova\Desktop\chromedriver.exe`" and correct it.

It might be possible that the *space* before `Users` breaks the path and hence the file isn't found.

It would be best to go to the location of the ***chromedriver.exe*** file in your *file browser* and then copy the path from there to get the correct path.

Comment: i used the correct path and i copied it but it doesn't recognise it, I don't know what to do T.T

Comment: Are you getting the same error? or does it give a different error now?

Comment: yes, I'm getting the same error

Comment: ok, I resolved the problem. I was using the 4th version of selenium so I had to use another code:                                                                                                            
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(r"C:\Users\giova\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"))
driver.get("https://www.google.com")